# Adding a SharePoint Subsite to my current MS Teams channel?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I was wondering if it's possible to add a SharePoint subsite to a MS Teams channel? The Teams channel is connected to a SharePoint site (of course), but I just want to see the subsite I created in SharePoint on the Teams channel.

Please let me know if you have any idea of how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a SharePoint or SharePoint pages tab to your Teams channel:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/add-a-sharepoint-page-list-or-document-library-as-a-tab-in-teams-131edef1-455f-4c67-a8ce-efa2ebf25f0b?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

Answer (score 0):

Add SharePoint Subsite to MS Teams channel

**Please follow steps:**

1.Go to MS Teams channel page. To the right of the channel name, select **+** on the tab bar.
[image]

2.On the **Add a tab** windows, select the **SharePoint** tab.
[image]

3.In the current Teams channel, select **Pages** section to see a list of existing SharePoint pages from your team site. And then select the SharePoint content to add as a tab in the Teams channel.
[image]

4.Or select **Any SharePoint site** option, entry your SharePoint subsite URL and post it.
[image]

[image]